# Mongoose.js: is it possible to populate array items by condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
    var PostSchema = new Schema({
    by: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'user' },
    body: String,
    likes: [{ by: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'user' }, isAnonymous: { type: Boolean, default: false}}],
});
```

This schema supports anonymous likes.

my question: is there a way to populate only the items in the 'likes' array where isAnonymous is equals to false?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, There is

```
opts={ 
        path: 'likes', 
        match: { 
                isAnonymous:false
        },
        select: '<fields to be fetched>'
};

Post
    .find({})
    .populate(opts)
```

[docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate)

[help](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/)